# Array.splice is not returning the correct output

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to match both arrays if they contain the same value, it will remove the element from one of the array. I tried using the `splice()` method. I tried read the however the output is:

```
new array ["SUGAR"]
```

However, I would like to achieve this output:

```
["HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL", "SUNFLOWER OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL"]
```

Here's the original array (`unSafe`):

```
["SUGAR", "HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL", "SUNFLOWER OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL"]
```

And here is my code:

```
function breakArray() {
  let warning = this.navParams.get("warningResult");
  let unSafe = this.navParams.get("unSafeResult");

  console.log(unSafe);
  console.log(warning);

  for (var i = 0; i < warning.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < unSafe.length; j++) {
      if (warning[i] === unSafe[j]) {
        console.log('warning', i);
        console.log('unSafe', j);

        unSafe.splice(j, 1);

        console.log('new array', unSafe);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `j` is 0.

```js
// Original array.
var unsafe = ["SUGAR", "HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL", "SUNFLOWER OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL"];

// Find the index of the item.
let removeIndexStart = unsafe.indexOf('SUGAR');

// Check if it exists.
if (removeIndexStart > -1) {
  // Returns the removed items (from index 0, removing 1 item)
  // and modifies the array in-place.
  var removed = unsafe.splice(removeIndexStart, 1);

  console.log('Removed:', JSON.stringify(removed, null, 2));
}

console.log('Modified:', JSON.stringify(unsafe, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

Try working in reverse:

```
for (var i = warning.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

And operating on the larger array, which is what you want.

```
warning.splice(i, 1);
```

```js
let warning = ["SUGAR", "HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL", "SUNFLOWER OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL"];
let unSafe =  ["SUGAR"];

breakArray(); // I would pass in arguments.

console.log('New array:', warning);

function breakArray() {
  for (var i = warning.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < unSafe.length; j++) {
      if (warning[i] === unSafe[j]) {
        console.log('warning', i);
        console.log('unSafe', j);

        warning.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Hi there, it is working now . As console.log shows 
0
:
"HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL"
1
:
"RAPESEED OIL"
2
:
"PALM OIL"
3
:
"SUNFLOWER OIL"
4
:
"RAPESEED OIL"
5
:
"PALM OIL"

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Use the `filter` method instead of the `splice` one. You don't want to splice on an array you are iterating on.

```js
let unsafeArray = ["SUGAR", "HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL", "SUNFLOWER OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL"];

let warningArray = ["SUGAR", "SUNFLOWER OIL"];

let filteredArray = unsafeArray;

warningArray.forEach(function (warningElement) {
  filteredArray = filteredArray.filter(function (unsafeElement) {
    return unsafeElement !== warningElement;
  });
});

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: You can always splice if you search backwards.

Comment: Yes you can, but filter is a bit simpler IMO

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine. Returns the array without the "warning" element.

```js
function breakArray() {
  //let warning = this.navParams.get("warningResult");
  //let unSafe = this.navParams.get("unSafeResult");
  var warning = ["SUGAR"];
  var unSafe = ["SUGAR", "HYDROGENATED VEGETABLE↵OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL", "SUNFLOWER OIL", "RAPESEED OIL", "PALM OIL"];

  //console.log(unSafe);
  //console.log(warning);

  for (var i = 0; i < warning.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < unSafe.length; j++) {
      if (warning[i] === unSafe[j]) {
        //console.log('warning', i);
        //console.log('unSafe', j);

        unSafe.splice(j, 1);

        console.log('new array', unSafe);
      }
    }
  }
}

breakArray();
```